# jQuery: check the value of all <select>s on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with several `<select>` elements on it.

I'd like to check that the value of all select elements is '0'. How can I do this elegantly?

Currently I have this:

```
var all_zero = true;
$('myform select').each(function() { 
  if ($(this).val() !== '0') { 
      all_zero = false;
  }
});
if (all_zero) { //do something
```

Does anyone know a nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Test for the value in the selector.

```
var non_zero = $('myform select[value!="0"]').length;

if (non_zero === 0) { //do something
```

So if there's no `select` that does not have the value `"0"`, `non_zero === 0` will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to do it, one way for getting it cleaner is only declaring a variable when necessary. like so:

```
$('myform select').each(function() { 
  if ($(this).val() !== '0') { 
      some_zero = true;
  }
});
if (!some_zero) { //do something
```

Comment: Possibly cleaner in terms of reading the code, but you end up polluting the global scope with variables that likely have no need to be there.

Comment: you're right, for sure. I was thinking of this being executed in the global scope so, all_zero was being declared the same way to. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nice and you can try :

```
var all_zero = $('myform select').filter(function(){return $(this).val()!='0'}).length>0
```